# Spark App args encoding

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, encoding, hdfs

Spark seems to use a platform encoding parameter for app args, but which one ?

I launch a spark application with arguments like this :

```
final List<String> params = createParamList(...)
sparkLauncher.addAppArgs(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]));
```

Seems to be platform dependant, on some platforms, encoding is wrong :

```
INFOS:   childArgs               [ [...] ---user=Syst??me]
```

User should be "Système"

I tried to set java opts file.encoding param to driver and executor, but I doesn't change anything.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thks

Comment: Seems like it's an issue with locale which isn't set correctly for the user used to launch Spark process.

Comment: I thought but on both platforms locale is set to en-US.UTF-8 for tomcat user (app is lauched from a tomcat webapp)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to an incorrectly set LANG environment variable at tomcat startup.

Can you execute `System.getenv("LANG");` just before your Spark submit ?